# Почему на слой нельзя прикрепить Qlabel?

Tags: qt

grid.h

```
#ifndef GRID_H
#define GRID_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QDir>
#include <QFileInfoList>  
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QFileIconProvider>
class grid : public QWidget
{
     Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit grid(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void  Root(QDir dir);
private:
    qint16 xItem,yItem;
    QGridLayout Grid;
    qint32 currentWigth;
    QDir RootDirect;
    QSize sizeHint();
    QIcon pix;
    QPixmap pix_pixmap;
    QVBoxLayout icon;
    QLabel img, name;
signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // GRID_H
```

grid.cpp

```
#include "grid.h"

grid::grid(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    QFileInfoList List =  RootDirect.entryInfoList(QDir::Files|QDir::Dirs|QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    QFileInfoList::iterator it;
    Grid.columnMinimumWidth(32);
    currentWigth = frameSize().width();
    xItem = currentWigth/32;
    yItem = List.count()/xItem;
    Grid.setColumnStretch(xItem,yItem);
    icon.addWidget(img);
    icon.addWidget(name);
    int count = 0;
    for (int y = 1; y != yItem; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 1; x !=xItem; x++)
        {
            count++;
            QFileIconProvider t;
            pix = t.icon(List.at(count));
            pix_pixmap = pix.pixmap(QSize(30,30));
            img.setPixmap(pix_pixmap);
            // нужно добавить к (y,x) элементу Grid слой icon
        }
    }
}

QSize grid::sizeHint()
{
    return QSize(256,0);
}
void grid::Root(QDir dir)
{
    RootDirect = dir;
}
```

Пытаюсь извлечь иконку из файла, а затем поставить ее на лейбл.
И вертикальный слой почему-то не принимает `Qlabel`, хотя он вроде как наследует `QWidget`. Также не могу понять как к элементу `Grid` прикрепить виджет.

Answer (score 0):

> "И вертикальный слой почему-то не принимает Qlabel, хотя он вроде как наследует QWidget"

Потому что ты не задал слой виджету. Добавь в коструктор:

```
grid::grid(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
...
   QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
   mainLayout->addLayout()
   this->setLayout(Grid);
   this->setLayout(icon);

  this->setLayout(mainLayout);
}
```

> "Также не могу понять как к элементу Grid прикрепить виджет."

[Примеры работы с слоями по ссылке](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-basiclayouts-example.html)